# How do I check if all items in a 2D list are all the same?

Tags: python

I need help checking if all the items in a two-dimensional list are the same (in this case, I'm checking if they are all equal to one).

I made a function `allOnes(L)` that checks if all items are 1's in a 1D array. I used the all() function like this:

```
def allOnes(L):
    """Tests to see if the numbers in the list L are all 1's
    """
    return all(x == 1 for x in L)
```

Now I need to check if all items in a 2D list are all 1's. I would like the function allOnes2d to return True when it checks a list like this: `[[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]`. Is this possible using `all()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def allOnes2d(L):
    return all(allOnes(a) for a in L)
```

And to do an array of any dimension, use [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to reduce the N-dimensional array to a regular one, then give it to your allOnes function. (Thanks to Lattyware)

Comment: [``itertools.chain``](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) is a better option than a list comprehension here.

Comment: Ah yes, that's much more apt. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For fast rectangular array use numpy.

```
import numpy
table= numpy.array([[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]])
print numpy.all( table == 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Though using `all()` and your defined function is a good way to do it, you can also look into this alternative

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sum(1 for e in chain(*[[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]) if e!= 1)
0
```

or you may also call `allOnes` after unwrapping the list through `itertools.chain`

```
>>> allOnes(chain(*[[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]))
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like recursion for this kind for thing:

```
from collections import Iterable
def allOnes(I):
    if isinstance(I, Iterable):
        return all(allOnes(i) for i in I)
    else:
        return I == 1
```

an example:

```
>>> L = [[1,1,1], (1,1,1), 1]
>>> allOnes(L)
True
>>> L = [[1,1,1], (1,0,1), 1]
>>> allOnes(L)
False
```